# Can i use Corelocation to create square region instead of circular for Geofencing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-location

Is it possible to create square regon for **geofencing** in `xamarin.ios` using **Corelocation**?.

If possible then how?. i am not getting any proper tutorial to follow.

Answer (score 1):

No, iOS only supports circular shaped regions for geofencing.